# sharing Arcpy codes

Tags: arcpy

What are the most common websites to share Arcpy codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of question you should always check out the ESRI [code sharing website](http://codesharing.arcgis.com/) first. It was previously known as ArcScripts.

Here you will find a wide range of user community created tools, including tools for splitting lines.